# How to convert strings into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, io, type-conversion

I have a `bytes` object which is what I want to make use of.

```
bytes_1 = {"granularity":"Monthly","main_domain_only":false,"mtd":false,"show_verified":false,"state":null,"page":null,"format":"json","domain":"website.com","start_date":"2019-10-01","end_date":"2021-10-31","country":"uk"},"status":"Success","last_updated":"2021-10-31"},"visits":[{"date":"2019-10-01","visits":42641.106198532005},{"date":"2019-11-01","visits":39084.75203858769},{"date":"2019-12-01","visits":75293.20188556636},{"date":"2020-01-01","visits":74846.32665257844},{"date":"2020-02-01","visits":53411.33746849558},{"date":"2020-03-01","visits":50202.09919672746},{"date":"2020-04-01","visits":83135.4077079868},{"date":"2020-05-01","visits":128402.42646177398},{"date":"2020-06-01","visits":142254.20581500718},{"date":"2020-07-01","visits":97795.90976634984},{"date":"2020-08-01","visits":153057.2435480025},{"date":"2020-09-01","visits":174668.65913280132},{"date":"2020-10-01","visits":128082.17226849863},{"date":"2020-11-01","visits":117737.94226795572},{"date":"2020-12-01","visits":139259.13459326507},{"date":"2021-01-01","visits":129572.35638477515},{"date":"2021-02-01","visits":104814.00413267144},{"date":"2021-03-01","visits":48927.388186319484},{"date":"2021-04-01","visits":30901.658623907377},{"date":"2021-05-01","visits":34564.981543265196},{"date":"2021-06-01","visits":51215.85515078678},{"date":"2021-07-01","visits":23632.959350567497},{"date":"2021-08-01","visits":32988.756167336134},{"date":"2021-09-01","visits":214154.73499697837},{"date":"2021-10-01","visits":22844.79558982703}]}'
```

There's a `start_date` and `end_date` argument that I can specify and it pulls daily `visits` data as an above format in a string, according to the date that I input.

For analyzing purposes, I want to convert the above string into dataframe but I can't really think of a way to make this work.

I start off by trying to convert this into the string and try `io.StringIO` but it's not working properly.

Comment: is the whole bytes object in string? I found some of the `]` and `'` are not matched in your example

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes_1` data can *almost be parsed as JSON.  If we make a few string edits we can create a DataFrame as follows:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# touch up the input data
bdata_fix = bytes_1.replace('"uk"},', '"uk",'). \
    replace('"last_updated":"2021-10-31"},', '"last_updated":"2021-10-31",'). \
    rstrip("'")

info = json.loads(bdata_fix)
df = pd.DataFrame(info['visits'])
```

gives us the data frame

```
          date         visits
0   2019-10-01   42641.106199
1   2019-11-01   39084.752039
2   2019-12-01   75293.201886
3   2020-01-01   74846.326653
4   2020-02-01   53411.337468
5   2020-03-01   50202.099197
6   2020-04-01   83135.407708
7   2020-05-01  128402.426462
8   2020-06-01  142254.205815
9   2020-07-01   97795.909766
10  2020-08-01  153057.243548
11  2020-09-01  174668.659133
12  2020-10-01  128082.172268
13  2020-11-01  117737.942268
14  2020-12-01  139259.134593
15  2021-01-01  129572.356385
16  2021-02-01  104814.004133
17  2021-03-01   48927.388186
18  2021-04-01   30901.658624
19  2021-05-01   34564.981543
20  2021-06-01   51215.855151
21  2021-07-01   23632.959351
22  2021-08-01   32988.756167
23  2021-09-01  214154.734997
24  2021-10-01   22844.795590
```

Comment: Great stuff!! Thank you very much